# Constructor overloading with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

As i have one `User` class having 2 parameters : first_name, last_name. So my kotlin class with be :

```
data class User(val first_name:String, val last_name:String)
```

Now i want a constructor which will accept only `first_name`, or you can say just one parameter. How can i define it with `Kotlin`?

I know we can pass default value and in that way we can ignore second parameter, but how can we write multiple constructor?

Comment: for this case .. you don't want to create another constructor.. because in Kotlin , we can use parameters as optional

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html

Comment: Why do you want a second constructor instead of a default value for last_name? And btw, in java and kotlin you should use CamelCase instead of SnakeCase

Answer (score 65):

You can define extra constructors in the class body

```
data class User(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) {

    constructor(firstName: String) : this(firstName, "")

}
```

These 'secondary constructors' have to call through to the primary constructor or a different secondary constructor. See the [Official documentation on constructors](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors).

So, in effect this is the same as just a primary constructor with default argument, which would be the idiomatic way to go.

```
data class User(val firstName: String, val lastName: String = "")
```

Answer (score 6):

I hope this will help you

```
class Person(val name: String, val age: Int = 0) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return name + " is " + age + " years Old"
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var person = Person(name = "vignesh")
    var personNew = Person("vignesh", 23)
    println(person.toString())
    println(personNew.toString())
}
```

Output

vignesh is 0 years Old

vignesh is 23 years Old

Answer (score 2):

If you are using data class, then you won't require another constructor. Just pass default value to your last_name parameter. 
If you are using a normal class then you can have secondary constructor 
Lets say you have class A

```
class A(val param:String,val param2:String){
 constructor(val param:String):this(param,"")
}
```

If you wish manipulate these values you can use init{} block where you can play around your constructor values.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

A class in Kotlin can have a primary constructor and one or more secondary constructors. The primary constructor is part of the class header: it goes after the class name (and optional type parameters).

```
class Person constructor(firstName: String) {
}
```

If the primary constructor does not have any annotations or visibility modifiers, the constructor keyword can be omitted:

```
class Person(firstName: String) {
}
```

Note that parameters of the primary constructor can be used in the initializer blocks. They can also be used in property initializers declared in the class body:

```
class Customer(name: String) {
    val customerKey = name.toUpperCase()
}
```

You can also follow this link as per your need : [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html)

Answer (score 1):

This sample of code works fine for me, you can customize them to your need.

```
data class Booking(
    var user: String,
    var bike: String
){
    constructor(
        user: String,
        bike: String,
        taken_at: String,
        returned_at: String
    ) : this (user, bike)
}
```

Comment: if we do this: `val x = Booking("foo", "bmx", "10am", "1030pm")`, how can we print out the values for `taken_at` and `returned_at`? seems like we can't do: `println(x.taken_at)` it doesn't work.

Comment: If you need to display them too, you can add their variable so that they can be accessed.