# How can I add multiple and empty constructor in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, constructor

I have this Java class and want to convert it to Kotlin, how can I have especially the empty constructor?

```
class Element {
int id;
Element element1;
Element element2;

public Element() {
}

public Element(int value) {
    this.id = value;
}

public Element(int value, Element element1, Element element2) {
    this.id = value;
    this.element1 = element1;
    this.element2 = element2;
}}
```

I tried like this:

```
class Element {
var id = 0
var element1: Element? = null
var element2: Element? = null

constructor() {}
constructor(value: Int) {
    id = value
}

constructor(value: Int, element1: Element?, element2: Element?) {
    id = value
    this.element1 = element1
    this.element2 = element2
}}
```

but when i try to access element.element1 and pass it to a function which expects Element, it says:

Type mismatch.
Required:Element
Found:Element?

I changed the function from

```
fun checkIfElementEqualsSearch(search: Int, rootElement: Element){...}
```

to

```
fun checkIfElementEqualsSearch(search: Int, rootElement: Element?{...}
```

Works like a charm now!

Thx for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constructor overloading with Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176210/constructor-overloading-with-kotlin)

Comment: Related: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when i try to access element.element1 and pass it to a function which expects Element, it says:
>
> Type mismatch. Required:Element Found:Element?
>
> How can I avoid this?

This is because the type of `element1` (actually `node1` now) in your `Element` class is nullable (`Element?` with question mark).
If a function is declared to accept `Element` (without question mark) it means it doesn't accept `null`.
Kotlin enforces this null-safety at compile time, which is why it's great.

You have several options depending on the behaviour you're looking for:

- make the function accept `Element?` instead of `Element` if it handles the null value in its own body
- use the [elvis operator `?:`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) to provide a fallback value or throw an exception in case your element is actually null:

  ```kotlin
  myFunction(element.node1 ?: someNonNullElement)

  myFunction(element.node1 ?: error("Something went wrong"))
  ```
- check for null and rely on smart cast to guarantee the element is not null:

  ```kotlin
  val elt = element.node1
  if (elt != null) {
      myFunction(elt)
  }
  ```